# Use LinkGenerator to generate urls in REST format

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have a test controller set up that returns a dummy book:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("", Name = "GetBook")]
public ActionResult GetBook(Guid id)
{
    return Ok(new Book
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Title = "The Grass is Always Greener",
        Author = " Jeffrey Archer",
        Description = "This ingenious tale examines the ambitions and petty jealousies of the staff at Critchley's Bank. From the doorman to the personnel manager, to Sir William, the bank's sorrowful chairman. Archer knits a panoply of characters with deft narrative skill in a story which is as revealing as it is observant. Taken from his anthology To Cut a Long Story Short, his other short story anthologies include A Quiver Full of Arrows, Twelve Red Herrings and A Twist in the Tale.",
        ISBN = "1-86092-049-7",
        Links = new Links
        {
            GET = _linkGenerator.GetUriByName(this.HttpContext, nameof(GetBook), new { id })
        }
    });
}
```

It uses _linkGenerator, which is injected in the constructor:

```
public BooksController(LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
{
    _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
}
```

The output of that GetUriByName call is the following:

```
https://localhost:7157/api/Books?id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

That works and gets the correct results, but it's not formatted in the REST notation, which would be:

```
https://localhost:7157/api/Books/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

**What do I need to do to get the correct REST notation as described?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not formated in REST notation

There is no such thing as "REST notation", that is a perfectly valid URL.

However, if you want to force the `id` parameter to be part of the route, then you need to tell the framework that. So update the `Route` attribute to be something like this:

```
[Route("{id}", Name = "GetBook")]
public ActionResult GetBook(Guid id)
...
```